# Mayores de 18 años: ¿incluye a personas de 18 años?

Tags: modismos, lenguaje-jurídico

La pregunta es retórica, pues todos sabemos que la respuesta es afirmativa: Mayores de 18 años: ¿incluye a personas de 18 años?
La verdadera pregunta refiere a la aparente contradicción entre este hecho y el **significado literal de la frase.**

Cualquier persona con formación matemática básica sabe que "21 > 18". Esto es, "21 es mayor que 18". Similarmente, "18 = 18". Sin embargo, la frase implica "18 > 18", lo que es un error.

Hubiera sido intuitivo, por ejemplo, para alguien que está aprendiendo español, que la expresión hubiera sido "para mayores de 17 años". En este caso, "18 > 17" es correcto.

¿Alguien tiene una explicación para esta aparente contradicción?

Nótese que el uso de esta expresión no es meramente coloquial. También se encuentra en leyes. Por ejemplo, el [artículo 116](https://leyes.co/codigo_civil/116.htm) del Código Civil Colombiano dice:

> Las personas mayores de 18 años pueden contraer matrimonio libremente.

Además, nótese que la frase "menores de X años" no sufre de esta ambigüedad. Esto es, dicha expresión **no** incluye a personas de X años.

Comment: Al minuto siguiente de cumplir 18 años ya uno es mayor de 18 años porque tiene 18 años y un minuto. Solo que si a uno le preguntan cuántos años tiene uno dice que 18 y no 18.000001 Pero obviamente 18.0000001 > 18     

Comment: @DGaleano Muy pocos saben el minuto de su nacimiento (además de los cambios de horario, differente zona horaria, etc). Probablemente la ley asume que la persona nació al segundo 12:00:00 del día de cumpleanos, en cuyo caso tu argumento es válido. Pero jamás he visto este supuesto hecho explícito.

Comment: No se trata de que uno sepa el minuto en que nació. Ya que tu pregunta menciona "matemáticas básicas" simplemente se trata de que **matemáticamente tienes 18 exactos solo por un instante** y a partir de ahí ya tienes más de 18 independientemente de si celebras tu cumpleaños a las 0:00 o si lo celebras por la tarde. Para todos los fines prácticos por encima de la escala de Planck el tiempo corre de manera continua y no hay porque limitarse a los números enteros para describirlo.

Comment: @DGaleano Pero en cuál instante? Es posible imaginar un caso donde uno, el día de cumpleaños, exige derecho a algo (p.ej. votar). Si la ley lo concede, entonces está asumiendo que el minuto en que la persona nació ya ocurrió ese día. Por default, podriamos decir entonces que la ley asume 12:00:00 como el **instante** de nacimiento.

Comment: Este stack es sobre español. No sobre leyes. El significado de mayor se puede ver en la [respuesta](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/31700/11102) de @fedorqui. Si eso no responde tu pregunta entonces esta es off-topic.

Comment: No consigo encontrar la noticia, pero recuerdo que hace unos años en España un juez tuvo en cuenta la hora de nacimiento de un homicida. Como cumplía los 18 años por la tarde y asesinó por la mañana, se le aplicaron cargos de menor de edad. Y sí, estoy de acuerdo con @DGaleano que la esencia de la pregunta en este sitio sería sobre el significado lingüístico, la ley es algo que aquí no debatimos.

Comment: @DGaleano Si están haciendo referencia a mi respuesta, no han entendido el punto. En mi respuesta sólo quise explicar cómo la ley, por su carácter estricto, aclara algo que a criterio de muchos legisladores **puede** ser ambiguo. La edad de los adultos se expresa en años. Si tengo 18 años y digo que tengo amigos mayores que yo, es muy probable que esos amigos no incluyan a los que tengan 18 y un mes, o 18 y dos meses, etc. sino a los que tengan a partir de 19 años. Respecto de los de 18 y n meses, diré que tienen **la misma edad** que yo.

Comment: @Gustavson disculpa pero no he leído tu respuesta. Estaba haciendo referencia solo a los comentarios previos aquí en la pregunta y no a ninguna de las respuestas.

Answer (score 3):

No entiendo dónde esta la ambigüedad. Las personas con 18 años y un día son matemáticamente mayores de 18 años. ¿o no?. Incluso con 18 años y un segundo.

-- EDITADO --

Como español nativo no veo el uso de esta expressión en absoluto ambiguo. Yo entiendo "18 años" como un punto en el tiempo : cuando la persona cumple 18 años. Por eso antes de este punto en el tiempo la persona en cuestión tiene 17 años y matemáticamente coincide que el número es menor. Después de ese punto en el tiempo si sólo nos fijamos en los años parece que haya una contradicción, porque los números coinciden. Pero realmente nos referimos a un punto posterior en el tiempo así que veo correcto decir "mayores de 18 años". Si dijeramos "mayores de 18 años y un minuto" no habría ambigüedad, pero no hemos cambiado gramatical o semánticamente nada en la frase.

Si nos fijamos en otros usos como : "vino más tarde de las cuatro", la expresión sigue siendo correcta aunque viniera a las cuatro y un minuto, aunque la hora sea la misma. Por eso yo no veo ninguna contradicción.

Comment: I guess my explanation is not clear enough. I understand "18 años" like a point in time and even one second after it is obviously after that point, so for me there is no contradiction: "mayores de 18 años" is after that point in time. The OT is asking for an explanation and that is what I provided.

Comment: Después de leer otra vez la respuesta veo que tienes razón. La he editado para tratar de formularlo lo más neutralmente posible.

Comment: 100% de acuerdo. +1

Answer (score 3):

18 años es la edad que **cumples** el día de tu 18º **cumple**años.

[**Cumplir**](https://dle.rae.es/?id=BfzDPj7) viene del latín *complēre*, como **completar**. Decimos que "cumplimos" años, y lo llamamos "cumple-años", porque ese día es el día en que *completamos* un año más.

> **cumplir**
>   `Del lat.`*`complēre`*`'llenar', 'completar'.`
>
> 3. tr. Llegar a tener la edad que se indica o un número cabal de años o meses. *Hoy cumple Juan catorce años.*

Nuestra edad no va por bloques, no vamos dando saltos de un año al siguiente; no tenemos la misma edad los 365 días del año. Dos personas que tengan ambas 18 años, salvo que hayan nacido el mismo día y a la misma hora (y minuto y segundo), no tienen la misma edad: siempre una será mayor que la otra.

El día que cumplimos 17 años tenemos 17 años; a los dos meses tenemos 17 años y 2 meses, a los 11 meses y 4 semanas tenemos aproximadamente 17 años y 362 días. Y 3 días después, tenemos **18 años *cumplidos*; es decir: completos**.
Y al día siguiente, tenemos 18 años y un día (aproximadamente 18.00274 años), una cantidad *mayor* que 18 años justos.

**Por eso se considera que toda persona que ha *cumplido* 18 años tiene, por definición, más de 18 años; es decir, es mayor de 18 años.**

Otra cosa es que en el día a día no nos molestemos (normalmente) en indicar cuántos meses, semanas y días tenemos además de los años. A efectos prácticos, a la mayoría nos basta con indicar los años, y ya está. Pero eso no quiere decir que los conceptos de "mayor de" y "menor de" no deban tenerlo en cuenta.

Comment: La edad, quiérase o no, se mide por años (excepto en los bebés, donde se habla de días, semanas o meses).

Comment: A lo que voy es que no es un tema de matemáticas. La lengua es ambigua en ese punto y el derecho debe desambiguarla.

Comment: @Gustavson De acuerdo. Es extremadamente que alguien diga su edad incluyendo meses o incluso días. Años es la norma.

Comment: 100% de acuerdo. +1

Answer (score 2):

El DLE recoge en su definición:

> [**mayor**](https://dle.rae.es/?id=OfcJXRh)
>
> 1. adj. Que excede a algo en cantidad o calidad.

Por tanto, etimológicamente el *mayor* lingüístico debería asociarse con el *mayor estricto* matemático.

Sin embargo, en el habla coloquial creo que se debe tender a evitar la ambigüedad, que podríamos conseguir [con la coma que sugiere user2325442](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/31698/1674) o bien con alguna otra fórmula del tipo:

> A partir de la fecha en que cumplen 18 años...

---

Nótese que no son raras este tipo de ambigüedades o desincronizaciones entre la acepción matemática y el uso lingüístico. Véase el caso también de la conjunción disyuntiva [*o*](https://dle.rae.es/?id=Qltkqeu), que en lenguaje matemático es "uno, otro o ambos", mientras que en el habla se deja en "uno u otro".

Answer (score 1):

Gramaticalmente, sería más correcto decir:

- Las personas pueden contraer matrimonio libremente a partir de los 18 años (de edad).
- Las personas de 18 o más años pueden contraer matrimonio libremente.

De este modo, quedaría claro que quien tenga 18 años cumplidos está legalmente habilitado para contraer matrimonio.

No obstante, en textos legales es una convención (extensiva a la lengua en general) que "mayor de" incluye y "menor de" excluye a quienes hayan cumplido la edad referenciada.

La ley argentina (habría que ver qué ocurre en otros cuerpos jurídicos) es bien explícita al respecto y, si bien utiliza la frase "mayor de 18 años", aclara:

`Artículo 126: Son menores las personas que no hubieren cumplido la edad de DIECIOCHO (18) años.` ([Ley 26.579](http://servicios.infoleg.gob.ar/infolegInternet/anexos/160000-164999/161874/norma.htm))

Más adelante, la misma ley dice:

> Toda disposición legal que establezca derechos u obligaciones hasta la
>   mayoría de edad debe entenderse **hasta los DIECIOCHO (18) años**, excepto
>   en materia de previsión y seguridad social en que dichos beneficios se
>   extienden hasta los VEINTIUN (21) años, salvo que las leyes vigentes
>   establezcan una edad distinta.

La ley debe ser muy clara, pues alguien podría argumentar que "mayor de 18" es quien tiene a partir de 19 años. El hecho de decir que la minoría de edad se extiende hasta los 18 deja en claro que al cumplirse esos años se adquiere la mayoría de edad.

En [este artículo del diccionario del español jurídico](https://dej.rae.es/lema/edad-para-contraer-matrimonio) se usa "a partir de" para delimitar con más claridad las edades, y partiendo de este artículo llegué a otro buen ejemplo que busca desambiguar la lengua vulgar, que es [la ley española](https://boe.es/buscar/act.php?id=BOE-A-1889-4763#art46):

> Artículo 315.
>   La mayor edad empieza **a los dieciocho años cumplidos**.
>
> Para el cómputo de los años de la mayoría de edad se incluirá completo el día del nacimiento.

He decidido terminar de editar esta respuesta con un comentario que hice arriba que me parece pertinente para que se entienda mi punto:

En mi respuesta sólo quise explicar cómo la ley, por su carácter estricto, aclara algo **de la lengua común** que a criterio de muchos legisladores **puede** ser ambiguo. La edad de los adultos se expresa en años. Si tengo 18 años y digo que tengo amigos mayores que yo, es muy probable que esos amigos no incluyan a los que tengan 18 años y 1 mes, o 18 años y 2 meses, etc. sino a los que tengan a partir de 19 años. Respecto de los de 18 y n meses, es muy probable que diga que tienen **la misma edad** que yo (sólo en algunos casos diré: Ah, pero tú eres mayor que yo porque me llevas X meses de diferencia).

Comment: People *mayores de 18 años* are those whose age is more than *18 años [y ningún día [ni hora [ni segundo]]]*. It's not a legal convention - it's pretty much sensible.

Comment: @23419 Law has to make things clear and cannot leave any room for ambiguity. "mayores de 18 años" is ambiguous. Counting days, hours and seconds when stating sb's age is ridiculous.

Answer (score -1):

Si,  de acuerdo con el sinsentido. Aunque se arregla con una coma:

> Las personas mayores, de 18 años (¡!)

@luchonacho,  siguiendo tu razonamiento sobre la literalidad equivoca de la frase, —con la que coincido, ya que **18 no es mayor, sino igual a 18**—, quise mostrar que gramaticalmente el problema se resuelve con una coma, ya que la expresión cambia.

Con la sola adición de una coma, pasa de requerir personas de más de 18 años, a definir a personas mayores **como habiendo cumplido 18 años** (lo cual vale para [la mayor parte de los países](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mayor%C3%ADa_de_edad#18_a%C3%B1os) —entre los que se encuentran España, Argentina, Bolivia, Chile, Costa Rica, Ecuador, El Salvador, México, Perú, Uruguay, etc)

Un pequeño ardid creativo, maña o artilugio humorístico, en el espíritu retórico de tu pregunta.

Comment: No veo como esto arregla la ambiguedad. Por favor, expláyate.

Comment: Ahí lo hice en el cuerpo de la respuesta, gracias por repreguntar

Comment: Mmm, pero eso implica dar una definición arbitraria a la palabra mayores, lo cuál es problemático por ejemplo si la frase se usa varias veces en un documento para indicar distintas edades (14, 18, 21, etc).

Comment: Ciertamente se necesita una definición, y esta lo es al establecer una noción clara, una linea divisoria, desde los 18 años en adelante se puede manejar, contraer matrimonio, votar etc.

Comment: En realidad el problema de la pregunta es pensar la edad en unidades de años. Estoy de acuerdo como se dijo aquí que la discusión se extravía por esa razón, mayor de 18 años es todo aquél que ha recorrido un tramo de **al menos** 18  años, lo cual comprende las micro-unidades del tiempo. Un instante, un segundo posterior, a eso supera el equivalente a esas 18 unidades de tiempo